# Ubuntu 19.04 Logitech K375s keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, 19.04, thinkpad, logitech

Logitech K375s keyboard is not found at all in Ubuntu 19.04 Bluetooth settings on Lenovo Thinkpad T490. Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try holding one of the Easy-Switch white buttons (F1, F2 or F3) until the LED on it rapidly blinks 3 times. Then the keyboard should become visible for Bluetooth pairing.

[Logitech K375s Seup Guide](https://www.logitech.com/assets/64928/k375s-multi-device.pdf)

Comment: I was aware of this setup guide but it doesn't work on Lenovo Thinkpad T490. If anybody has any luck with it working on Lenovo Thinkpad T490 please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Logitech_Unifying_Receiver) there is a list of options how to install unifying.

For me installation followed by the `pair` command with turning the keyboard on/off worked after the second trial:

```
sudo apt install ltunify
sudo ltunify pair
```